# CSS attribute selectors taking precedence over normal CSS class selectors

Tags: html, css

I originally noticed this problem when working with CSS in an SVG file, and thought it was rendering error, but after trying it in HTML, the same situation occurred.

Take the following code:

```
.example {color:green}
.example {color:blue}
```

In this case, as expected using normal class selectors, the value of `color` is initially `green`, though later in the file it is redefined as `blue`, thus the resulting color of elements in the class are blue.

Now take this example:

```
div[class='example'] {color:green}
.example {color:blue}
```

In this case, now initially defining the color value for divs in `example` using attribute selectors, when the value is redefined using normal CSS class selectors, the change from green to blue is ignored in the divs, and the value set by the attribute selector takes precedence, despite the blue color value for the whole class being redeclared later in the file.

According to Mozilla documentation on [CSS class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors), it says normal selectors and attribute selectors are "equivalent", though that doesn't appear to be the case in this situation. What is the cause of this?

Comment: Your first CSS rule is looking for *two* conditions (a div **and** a specific attribute), whereas your second is only looking for *one* condition (class). While an attribute selector *on it's own* may be equivalent, your first example includes two conditions - because it is more specific, it will take precedence.

Comment: Agreed.  @Santi is correct.  To have a simple attribute selector, you would need to change your style rule to be for `[class='example']` dropping the `div` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd originally posted this as a comment, but perhaps I should've made it answer.

---

Let's look at the actual conditions of your two CSS rules:

```
div[class='example'] {color:green}
```

- Element must be a `<div>`
- Element must have class "example"

```
.example {color:blue}
```

- Element must have class "example"

---

Because your first CSS rule has *two* conditions, whereas your second rule only has *one*, the first rule is more specific - therefore it will take precedence.

If you were to remove the `div` portion from your first rule, it would be considered equivalent (as MDN states), at which point the text would be blue.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My logic originally was backwards, as I assumed that the broader definition took precedence over more specific definitions, but when breaking it down into conditional statements, the concept makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla documentation is correct. 
But when considering specificity, you need to take in to the account `div` and `[class='example']`.
These two combined are stronger than `.example`.

Here is an nice representation of specificity:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

If you go and open smasingmagazine.com articele, you will conclude that:

`.example` has power of 10

Whereas `div[class='example']` has power of 11